# SQL Retrieve the number of values contain the same first word?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to write a SQL query to compute how many film titles have the same first word as 20 or more other films in the database.

For example, if 23 films contained the first word ‘SHREK’ in the title and 26 films contained the word ‘PUPPY’ in the title, the output should look like:

First_Word ________Count

```
   SHREK          23 
   PUPPY          26
```

Comment: The first place to start is always to try something...

Comment: sorry guys I tried various ways but none of them worked so I didn't bother to upload them

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUBSTR(FILM_TITLE, 1, INSTR(FILM_TITLE, ' ', 1) - 1),
       COUNT(*)
  FROM FILM_TABLE
 GROUP BY SUBSTR(FILM_TITLE, 1, INSTR(FILM_TITLE, ' ', 1) - 1)
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 20;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using REGEXP_SUBSTR**

```
WITH DATA AS(
SELECT 'SHREK THE MOVIE' str FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'PUPPY THE MOVIE' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'SHREK THE MOVIE' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'PUPPY THE MOVIE' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'SHREK THE MOVIE' FROM dual
)
SELECT regexp_substr(str, '\w+') sub_str, count(*) sub_str
FROM DATA
GROUP BY regexp_substr(str, '\w+')
/

SUB_STR            SUB_STR
--------------- ----------
SHREK                    3
PUPPY                    2

SQL>
```

**Using SUBSTR + INSTR**

```
WITH DATA AS(
SELECT 'SHREK THE MOVIE' str FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'PUPPY THE MOVIE' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'SHREK THE MOVIE' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'PUPPY THE MOVIE' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'SHREK THE MOVIE' FROM dual
)
SELECT SUBSTR(str, 1, INSTR(str, ' ', 1) - 1) sub_str, count(*)
FROM DATA
GROUP BY SUBSTR(str, 1, INSTR(str, ' ', 1) - 1)
/

SUB_STR           COUNT(*)
--------------- ----------
SHREK                    3
PUPPY                    2

SQL>
```

**Update**

For single word movie names, the above `SUBTR + INSTR` method would fail. Need to use `CASE`construct to fix it.

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 'SHREK' str FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'PUPPY THE MOVIE' FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 'SHREK THE MOVIE' FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 'PUPPY THE MOVIE' FROM dual UNION ALL
  6  SELECT 'SHREK THE MOVIE' FROM dual
  7  )
  8  SELECT
  9    CASE
 10      WHEN INSTR(str, ' ', 1) = 0
 11      THEN str
 12      ELSE SUBSTR(str, 1, INSTR(str, ' ', 1) - 1)
 13    END sub_str,
 14    COUNT(*)
 15  FROM DATA
 16  GROUP BY
 17    CASE
 18      WHEN INSTR(str, ' ', 1) = 0
 19      THEN str
 20      ELSE SUBSTR(str, 1, INSTR(str, ' ', 1) - 1)
 21    END
 22  /

SUB_STR           COUNT(*)
--------------- ----------
SHREK                    3
PUPPY                    2

SQL>
```

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar, Nice catch. Added an update to answer.

Comment: There can't be more than 20 movies with the same name :P

Comment: So? Just a `HAVING` clause is needed which is expected by OP to do it.